# NumPy slicing gives IndexError: too many indices for array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a sample numpy array read from a file like this:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([(b'M', 119.,  76.), (b'M', 114.,  73.), (b'F', 124.,  79.)],
dtype=[('gender', 'S1'), ('bps', '<f8'), ('bpd', '<f8')])
```

How to get the first column called `gender`?

I tried:

```
gender = data[:,0] # fails
gender = [i[0] for i in data] # pass
```

**Is there easier way to get the first column without list comprehension?**

**Can we unpack 3 columns like g,b,p=*data?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your `data` doesn't have a *column*. It is just a 1d array.

```
data.shape
(3, )
```

So the slicing will raise `IndexError` as you passed 2d indices.

Try:

```
list(zip(*data))[0]
# (b'M', b'M', b'F')
```

Comment: Congrats @Chris for 1k!

Answer (score 2):

You made a 1d structured array (with a compound `dtype`):

```
In [717]: data = np.array([(b'M', 119.,  76.), (b'M', 114.,  73.), (b'F', 124., 
     ...:  79.)],
     ...: dtype=[('gender', 'S1'), ('bps', '<f8'), ('bpd', '<f8')])
In [718]: 
In [718]: data.shape
Out[718]: (3,)
In [719]: data.dtype.fields
Out[719]: 
mappingproxy({'gender': (dtype('S1'), 0),
              'bps': (dtype('float64'), 1),
              'bpd': (dtype('float64'), 9)})
```

`fields` are accessed by name, not a column number:

```
In [720]: data['gender']
Out[720]: array([b'M', b'M', b'F'], dtype='|S1')
```

And element of this array is:

```
In [721]: data[0]
Out[721]: (b'M', 119., 76.)
In [722]: type(_)
Out[722]: numpy.void
```

We call that a `record`, but it does display (and index) as a tuple.  Note that your creation expression uses a list of tuples.

One way of unpacking the array is to iterate over the field names:

```
In [734]: data.dtype.names
Out[734]: ('gender', 'bps', 'bpd')
In [735]: a,b,c = [data[name] for name in data.dtype.names]
In [736]: a
Out[736]: array([b'M', b'M', b'F'], dtype='|S1')
In [737]: b
Out[737]: array([119., 114., 124.])
In [738]: c
Out[738]: array([76., 73., 79.])
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, Honestly I did not know `data.dtype.fields`.

Comment: This is the complete answer with `index error solution` and `unpacking`, SORRY, but Chris was the first to answer and crossed the milestone of 1k, so accepted his answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a ndarray , you have `array(tuple,tuple,tuple)`

```
data.shape
(3,)
```

Convert it to `ndarray` then you can slice by using the columns and index

```
np.array(data.tolist())[:,0]
array([b'M', b'M', b'F'], dtype='|S5')
```

More info :

```
np.array(data.tolist()).shape
(3, 3)
```

Comment: It has `np.array` at the beginning, I thought whatever is inside, we get `numpy n-darry`.

Comment: @astro123 see the shape . after convert it become 3,3

Comment: Got it, will use `data[:,None]`  which might be simpler than `tolist()`.